# Rails: Sql injection concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-injection

My controller finds a user using:

```
@user = User.find_by_identifier!(params[:id])
```

In my Users model, i have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

      def to_param
        identifier
      end

private 

  def create_identifier
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(9)
  end
end
```

Question: Is this safe from an SQL injection point? And how so, since I have no clue about SQL injection despite reading various articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick experiment in my own console indicates that `find_by_identifier!` is safe against SQL injection.

```
irb(main):005:0> User.find_by_email! "i am sneaky '; drop table woot;"
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'derp ''; drop table woot;' LIMIT 1
```

Notice how the generated SQL query escapes the malicious single-quote.

I believe that the `to_param` and `create_identifier` in your model are irrelevant.

Comment: That makes sense. I also have another sql query which uses a where conditional in the Users model. I use it in the index action to fetch users from the same city as the current_user: 
`scope :same_city, lambda { |user| joins(:profile).where(:profiles => {:city => user.profile.city})}`
 Would this be a threat? Sorry, I am a complete noob (despite all the points and badges I have racked up on this site)

Comment: This is explained in the [Active Record Query Interface Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions)